# Sample Space of a Product of Random Variables

Tags: discrete-mathematics, random-variables

Given a fair coin with $1$ on one side and $0$ on the other, $X$ is defined as "result of 1st coin flip" and $Y$ is "sum of results of both flips". $Z$ is defined as "$X·Y$".

For example, $X=1 = \{10, 11\}$, and $Y=1 = \{10, 01\}$, and $Z=X·Y$ would simply be $0$. My problem is that I don't know how to figure out the sample space for $Z$, since something like $10·11$ doesn't make any sense. Also unclear on the cardinality of the sample space.

I need the sample space of $Z$ to find $(X = x \wedge Z = z)$ when checking if $X$ & $Y$ are independent random variables (or at least that's my impression).

Comment: Do you understand what I want to say? Hopefully it is clear. ;) Interesting and good question. The trick is that you do need to model as containing every time the number of flips, not the total results. Maybe they could have explained this a bit better in the question. ;) Your model is fine (and would also be my first choice!), but I think they are looking for an other model, which you couldn't know if you are new in the field. ;)

Comment: So you mean instead of $X=1 = \{10, 11\}$, just simplify to $X=1 = \{1\}$?

Comment: You could do that (and that is what I would do). However, you don't need to do that. Remember that a random variable is actually a function from the sample space to $\mathbb{R}$. When you evaluate an expression as $P(X(\omega) = 1)$, often written shortly as  $P(X = 1)$, what you actually do is first evaluating what is between your probability measure $P$ and you first find the $\omega \in \Omega$ which are mapped to $1$ by your function $X : \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: So an other option would be that you map multiple events to a certain value with your random variable function. So for instance $\{10, 11\}$ could both be mapped to $1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First option:** Just concatenate the values and use the sample space $\{1010, 1001, 1110, 1101\}$.

**Second option:**
Change the sample space to let it represent the number of positive events happened. Then it resembles more closely your random variables.

The sample space $\Omega_X$ of the random variable for the first coin flip can be modeled as $\{0, 1\}$ and the sample space $\Omega_Y$ of the results of random variable taking on the sum of the result of the first two flips can be modeled as $\{0, 1, 2\}$. The sample space $\Omega_Z$ of the random variable of the product of both random variables can now be modeled as $\{0, 1, 2\}$

Comment: For the first option, I'm unclear as how to find $(X = x \wedge Z = z)$ since Z defined as {1010,1001,1110,1101} would clearly be ∅. Also for the second option, how would it work since the 1 in {0,1} would be different than the 1 in {0,1,2}?

Comment: Nope $Z$ isn't defined that way! :) Really good question now. $Z$ , because it is a random variable, can be defined in an other way as your sample space itself!! In fact, technically, $Z$ is even a function, I know, this seems really strange, it is to me either, but it is. And when you have something as $P(X = 1)$ you actually mean $P(X(\omega) = 1)$ and, and this might be strange, you first need to evaluate the equation $X(\omega) = 1$ then and this returns 'events' which are subsets, and these subsets are then feeded to the function $P$ your measure function which returns your probability.

Comment: With $\omega \in \Omega$, and here $\omega$ is called an event and $\Omega$ is called the sample space. An event is a subspace of the sample space and can contain for instance two singleton events (a singleton event is an event containing only 1 member of $\Omega$). So $\omega$ can be $\{1010,1001\}$ if $\Omega$ is the sample space $\{1011,1001,1110,1101 \}$. Yes, I know, we are going a bit theoretical now, but this is really interesting matter and things we actually all need to know when working with probabilities.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot for your help.